# plot a bar chart using matplotlib - type error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a frequency distribution (of occurences of words and their frequency)

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'peach']

plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show
```

However, i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = np.arange(0,len(y)) + 0.75
xl = ['', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'peach']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x,y,0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(xl)
ax.set_xlim(0,5.5)
```

It would be interesting if there is a better method for setting the labels to be in the middle of the bars.

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067389/matplotlib-barplot-generic-way-of-setting-the-xticklabels-in-the-middle-of-the), there is a better solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
# adding 0.75 did the trick but only if I add a blank position to `xl`
x = np.arange(len(y))
xl = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'peach']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x,y,0.5, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(xl)
```

Comment: got this error: in <module>
    ax.bar(x,y) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: The code works on my computer. I edited it. Please try again.

Comment: yes it works. i forgot that my y list was in string format as well. Had to transform it to integer. Thank you :)

Comment: @Moritz You shouldn't *add* questions in answers. If you have a question, *add* a question ;)

Comment: yeah, you are right. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: No, but you could add a reference to your question. It will be helpful to anybody that comes across here.

Answer (score 2):

Just add two lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x_name = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'peach']
x = np.arange(len(x_name))  # <--
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, x_name)  # <--
plt.show()
```

[image]

Plot `plt.bar(x_name, y)` directly will be supported in `v2.1`, see here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8959