# matplotlib barplot, generic way of setting the xticklabels in the middle of the bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following code generates a barplot with the xticklabels centered for each bar. However, scaling the x-axis, changing the number of bars or changing the bar width does alter the position of the labels. Is there a generic way of dealing with that behaviour ?

```
# This code is a hackish way of setting the proper position by trial
# and error.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
# adding 0.75 did the trick but only if I add a blank position to `xl`
x = np.arange(0,len(y)) + 0.75
xl = ['', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'peach']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x,y,0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(xl)
# I cannot change the scaling without changing the position of the tick labels
ax.set_xlim(0,5.5)
```

The suggested and working solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = np.arange(len(y))
xl = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'mango', 'peach'] 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x,y,0.5, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(xl)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem is that you only call `ax.set_xticklabels`. This fixes the labels, but the tick positions are still handled by the [`AutoLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator), which will add/remove ticks upon changing the axis limits.

So you also need to fix the tick positions:

```
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(xl)
```

By calling `set_xticks` the `AutoLocator` is replaced under the hood with a [`FixedLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator).

And then you can center the bars to make it look nicer (optional):

```
ax.bar(x, y, 0.5, align='center')
```

Comment: your answer is more comprehensive, so I'll remove mine to avoid duplicating the same answer. OP, you also need to remove the initial blank tick label before `'apple'`

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice that there are 6 labels but only five data points.

Comment: The initial blank tick label was necessary in order to get the centred labels. Otherwise my solution would not work.

Comment: Yes, in this specific example. But its completely random how many empty labels you would have to add in the generic case

Comment: That is the reason why I asked the question. It is an integral part of it.